# CGEvent.setIntegerValueField(_ field: CGEventField, value: Int64) not working?

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I've the following (working) code:

```
if NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.TextEdit").count != 0 {
    let pid = NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.TextEdit")[0].processIdentifier
  
    let qKeyDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: keyCode, keyDown: true)
    qKeyDown?.flags = .maskCommand
    qKeyDown?.postToPid(pid)
   }
```

However, when I add

```
qKeyDown?.setIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventAutorepeat, value: 1)
```

the CGEvent won't be posted or at least, it doesn't get received by the pid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have the `core-graphics` tag on this question? It doesn't appear to have anything to do with Core Graphics.

Comment: Because CGEvent is part of the CoreGraphics Framework.